# How to add billing details to source Stripe API

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I'm trying to insert the billing address from a Form into a Stripe source using the Stripe API and PHP.

This is what I am currently trying:

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  //Get form data and load it into DB and Stripe
  $address = stripslashes($_REQUEST['address']);
  $city    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['city']);
  $state   = stripslashes($_REQUEST['state']);
  $zip     = stripslashes($_REQUEST['zip_code']);

  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("MY-API-KEY");
      
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::updateSource(
    $ss_customer_id,
    $ss_card_id,
    [
      'billing_address' => [
        'line1' => $address,
      ]
    ]
  );
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as the Stripe API gives me the following response:

```
parameter_unknown - billing_address
Received unknown parameter: billing_address
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to Stripe docs https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update, you should use param **address**, which contains *city*, *country*, *line1*, *line2*, *postal_code*, *state*.

In your case I guess

```
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::update(
          $ss_customer_id,
          [
            'address' => [
              'line1' => $address,
            ]
          ]
        );
```

Comment: Ok I think i tried this but i will try again using your method. I will comment if it does not work.

Comment: I got the API response of parameter_unknown - address
Received unknown parameter: address

Comment: Sorry, now I'm see "updateSource" is not  same as updating customer data. 
As I can see, you use old version of PHP SDK.
Address is the part of customer entity, so the method should be Customer::update() instead.
I have clarified my answer.

Comment: This worked thanks so much, Now  I can add the other feilds.